# Should the timestamp() function in Cypher remain constant throughout a transaction?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The [Neo4j](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-timestamp) documentation indicates that the timestamp() function

> will return the same value during the whole one query, even if the
>   query is a long running one.

In my case, it would be helpful to have the value remain constant throughout a transaction, (so that various node and relationship timestamp properties I'm setting align with one another), but this does not appear to be the current behaviour.

My question is if the timestamp function *should* return the same value for an entire transaction, or if it is necessary for it to work the way it does now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Neo4j team considered this question and has indicated that the current behaviour (i.e. `timestamp()` should return a constant value within a query, but not over an entire transaction) is appropriate.

See here for more details: https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/2379.